# Compiling PCL on Pandaboard, linking error

Tags: ros, pcl, pandaboard, linking

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I've been stuck for a while now trying to get PCL to compile on my Pandaboard. The issue is with some libvtk library, which I've never heard of. Searching google did not yield much promising results either.

The linking error I'm getting is this :

```
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.6.1/../../../../lib/libvtkIO.so: undefined reference to `__aeabi_d2lz@libmysqlclient_16'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.6.1/../../../../lib/libvtkIO.so: undefined reference to `__aeabi_f2lz@libmysqlclient_16'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.6.1/../../../../lib/libvtkIO.so: undefined reference to `__aeabi_f2ulz@libmysqlclient_16'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.6.1/../../../../lib/libvtkIO.so: undefined reference to `__aeabi_d2ulz@libmysqlclient_16'
```

Some mismatch with libmysqlclient and libvtk? I don't know what to do from here, any help is appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32149/compiling-pcl-on-pandaboard,-linking-error/) by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1909 on 2012-04-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-04-18**:
Please post a link to which directions you are following for compiling PCL. Also, if this is PCL-standalone, not trying to compile PCL in ROS on a Pandaboard, you should probably send email to the pcl-users mailing list.

**Comment by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) on 2012-04-18**:
This is the perception_pcl stack, which was downloaded through ROS Desktop Full installation. I did not follow any directions other than the installation guide of ROS for Ubuntu. After that I added pcl as dependency and let it compile, with --rosdep-install added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

pcl needs the newer version of mysql.  Unfortunately there's a patch which breaks the ABI.  Make sure you have the lucid-updates repository added and update mysql.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0